# Mass create instances of models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In front of me on a sheet of paper, I have a list of 107 Names, Hometowns, Dates of Birth, and Genders.

In my Rails application, I ran

`rails g scaffold Person name hometown dob gender`.

Do I have to manually add each Person to the database through the form that was created? Is there a way to do this from my text editor instead?

Comment: What is the list's structure? Need more info to provide solution.

Comment: You could write a method that does it but if they're on paper you'd still need to input all the data or you could do it in console, again you'd still need to type the data in.

Comment: @Baloo - I know that I'm going to have to input them somewhere. But is there a more efficient way to do it than through submitting them to a form each and every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `seed.rb` file in your `db` folder. You can execute arbitrary Ruby statements to create your objects and save (or update) them to your database.
Simply list a bunch of statements like this one and execute the `db:seed` Rake task.

```
Person.create(:name => 'Bob', :hometown => 'Bobington', :dob => '1980-06-25', :gender => 'male')
```

Note that the task will fail if one of the created records fails a unique check or something similar (i.e. cannot be inserted into the db). Use other rake tasks (`db:drop`, `db:create`, `db:migrate`) to 'clean' the db if you can or empty the tables by hand if you cannot wipe it.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I was looking for. Let me try this out. Do I need to run `rake db:migrate` after `db:seed`?

Comment: @DylanRichards no, you need to run it BEFORE `db:seed`.

Comment: Exactly. Seed is the last step when setting up your database. I extended the answer to also make note of possible problems when the database is not empty when executing the seed. Note that you can always debug the seed file to track down errors.